# Why doesn't useRef trigger a child rerender in this situation?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web-applications, react-hooks

I'm running into an issue where my hobbies list is not being displayed if it was previously undefined.

The goal is to cycle through a list of hobbies and display them in the UI. If one hobby is passed, only one should be displayed. If none are passed, nothing should be displayed.

Basically, `setHobbies(["Cycling"])` followed by `setHobbies(undefined)` correctly turns off the hobbies render, but then the next `setHobbies(["Reading"])` doesn't show up.

Using a debugger I've been able to verify that the relevant code in the useEffect hook in EmployeeInfoWrapper does get triggered, and hobbiesRef.current set accordingly, but it doesn't cause EmployeeInfo to rerender.

Container:

```
const Container = () => {
  const [hobbies, setHobbies] = React.useState<string[]>();
  setLabels(["Board games"]); // example of how it's set; in reality this hook is passed down and set in lower components
  return (
    <SpinnerWrapper hobbies=hobbies otherInfo=otherInfo />
  );
};
```

EmployeeInfoWrapper:

```
export const EmployeeInfoWrapper = (props) => {
  const { hobbies, otherInfo } = props;
  const [indx, setIndx] = React.useState<number>(0);
  // this doesn't work due to https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14490, shouldn't matter though because it's handled in the useEffect 
  const hobbyRef = React.useRef(hobbies?.length ? hobbies[indx] : "");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hobbies?.length > 1) { // doubt this is relevant as my bug is with 0 or 1-length hobbies prop
      hobbyRef.current = hobbies[indx];
      setTimeout(() => setIndx((indx + 1) % hobbies.length), 2000);
    }

    if (hobbies?.length == 1) {
      hobbyRef.current = hobbies[indx]; // can see with debugger this line is hit
    }

    if (!hobbies?.length) { // covers undefined or empty cases
      hobbyRef.current = "";
    }
  }, [hobbies]);

  return (
    <EmployeeInfo hobby={hobbyRef.current} otherInfo={otherInfo} />
  );
};
```

Comment: What happens whenn you set it to undefined after the component mounts?

Comment: Setting a ref.current doesn't trigger a rerender.